# Responding to drop down selection change in angular without model binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have a drop down that should cause a data fetch on change. I don't need two way binding to a model for the drop down. I just want it initially populated with a list of departments and when a user selects one, it gets the list of users in that department.

The select looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selDepartmentList" ng-model="departmentList" ng-change="getUsersInDepartment(document.getElementById("selDepartmentList").options[document.getElementById("selDepartmentList").selectedIndex].value)">
        <option value="-1">All</option>
        <option ng-repeat="dept in departmentList"
                value="{{dept.DepartmentId}}">
                {{dept.DepartmentName}}
        </option>
</select>
```

I tried ng-change without ng-model, but it fails since ng-change requires ng-model for some reason. I tried setting ng-model to null and empty string, but neither worked. I also tried not using ng-change at all and using onchange, but getUsersInDepartment can't be found through onchange since it's attached to my controller. With ng-model set to departmentList, the drop down won't hold a value, any selection is erased.

All I want to have happen is that when a user selects a department it passes the id for that department to getUsersInDepartment, which will then fetch the user list. But right now getUsersInDepartment is never called.

departmentList is defined in my controller and attached to $scope. All the examples I've seen have some kind of selectedModelObject that they bind to the drop down. I don't have one of those.

My controller looks like:

```
controller('AdminTableCtrl', function ( $scope, coreAPIservice ) {
    $scope.userList = [];
    $scope.departmentList = [];

    coreAPIservice.GetUserList().success(function (response) {
        $scope.userList = response;
    });

    coreAPIservice.GetDepartmentList().success(function (response) {
        $scope.departmentList = response;
    });

    $scope.getUsersInDepartment = function(deptId) {
        if(deptId === -1) {
            coreAPIservice.GetUserList().success(function (response) {
                $scope.userList = response;
            });
        }
        else {
            coreAPIservice.GetUsersInDepartmentList(deptId).success(function (response) {
                $scope.userList = response;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Edit:

My original attempt with ng-options:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selDepartment"
                                        ng-model="selectedDepartment"
                                        ng-options="dept as dept.DepartmentName for dept in departmentList track by dept.DepartmentId">
            <option value="">Select Team...</option>
</select>
```

selectedDepartment is defined as:

```
$scope.selectedDepartment = {};
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use ng-model, it's so easy and straightforward... It's supposed to be so...

Comment: I find it confusing and obtuse.

Comment: I don't think there is another way that isn't an hack in angular. My opinion is to use it and don't lose too time thinking how to avoid it, instead I will focus on having a clear idea how it works and how it won't be confusing anymore.

Comment: "I find it confusing and obtuse" - What? right now, you are trying to make a call to a JQuery function through an angular `ng-click` handler, but think that using only angular is obtuse?  This could be done all in one statement using `ng-options`.

Comment: There is no JQuery anywhere in my application or in this example.

Comment: ng-options was the first thing I tried, but it wouldn't work. The select wouldn't populate. When I switched to ng-repeat it populated.

Comment: `document.getElementById` is definitely not angular.  I'm glad that you found a way to solve it without using angular, but I think `ng-options` would have worked fine;  it's hard to know for certain why it didn't work for you, however, without seeing the code you tried.

Comment: I updated with my original ng-options attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to avoid decorating the `<select>` element with any angular directives and instead place `ng-click` on each `<option>`.

Like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selDepartmentList">
        <option value="-1" selected>All</option>
        <option ng-repeat="dept in departmentList"
                                ng-click="getUsersInDepartment(dept.DepartmentId)"
                                value="{{dept.DepartmentId}}">
                                {{dept.DepartmentName}}
        </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not working and also it is not proper to set `click` event in `option` tag.

Comment: What if you change the value with the keyboard and not with a click?

Answer (score 0):

Making a custom directive should work for this problem.

```js
    angular
        .module('my_module')
        .directive('ngCustomChange', function($parse) {
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var fn = $parse(attrs.ngCustomChange);
                element.bind('change', function(event) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        fn(scope, {$event:event});
                    });
                });
            };
    });
```

```html
<select ng-custom-change="$ctrl.myFunction()">
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```