# ng-change does not work, directive cant be found

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<select id = "email_templates" name = "email_templates" class="chosen-select input-md form-control" ng-change = "alert('template selected');">
 <option  value="0">No template selected</option>
 <option value="1">Template 1</option>                                                     
</select>
```

I get the following error.

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!
```

All other angular directives seem to be working fine. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the ng-model for the select,

```
<select id = "email_templates" ng-model="selected" name = "email_templates" class="chosen-select input-md form-control" ng-change = "alert('template selected');">
 <option  value="0">No template selected</option>
 <option value="1">Template 1</option>                                                     
</select>
```

Comment: There's a typo in ng-model=""selected". An unecessary quotation mark :)

Answer (score 0):

ng-change reuires ng-model so use ng-model with ng-change

```
 <select id = "email_templates" ng-model="selected" name =
     "email_templates" class="chosen-select input-md form-control" ng-
      change = "alert('template selected');">
      <option  value="0">No template selected</option>
      <option value="1">Template 1</option>                                                     
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [`ng-change` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

> The `ngChange` expression is only evaluated when a change in the input
>   value causes a new value to be committed to the model.
>
> ...
>
> **Note, this directive requires `ngModel` to be present.**

`ng-change` creates a **watcher** for a variable of your model. So, you have to add a `ng-model` to your select, in order to tell Angular for which variable you observe changes.

```
<select ng-model="selectedEmail" ng-change="alert('template selected');">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select id = "email_templates" name = "email_templates" class="chosen-select input-md form-control" ng-change = "alert('template selected');">
 <option  value="0">No template selected</option>
 <option value="1">Template 1</option>                                                     
</select>
```

instead of this you can use ngClick on the option. As per this question [Responding to drop down selection change in angular without model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257719/responding-to-drop-down-selection-change-in-angular-without-model-binding)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<select id = "email_templates" name = "email_templates" class="chosen-select input-md form-control" >
 <option  value="0">No template selected</option>
 <option value="1" ng-click="alert('template selected');">Template 1</option>                                                     
</select>
```

Comment: if I use ng-click won't work properly in MAC OS Google chrome.